# Add shadow around a bubble tooltip

Tags: html, css

I have implemented a bubble tooltip in my application.I have written this css for creating it:

```
 .tooltipDemo
        {           
            position: relative;
            display: inline;
            text-decoration: none;
            left: 5px;
            top: 0px;     
        }
        .tooltipDemo:hover:before
        {
            border: solid;
            border-color: transparent #E5E4E2;
            border-width: 6px 6px 6px 0px;
            bottom: 21px;
            content: "";
            left: 155px;
            top: 5px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 95;          
        }
        .tooltipDemo:hover:after
        {
            background: #fff;
           background: #E5E4E2;
            border-radius: 5px;
            color: #666;
            width: 150px;
            left: 160px;
            top: -5px;           
            content: attr(alt);
            position: absolute;           
            padding: 5px 15px;          
            z-index: 95;           
        }
```

HTML Code:

```
 <a href="#" alt="Please Enter Name" class="tooltipDemo">   
                                   <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton19" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl="Images/customer-logo-01.jpg"  />

    </a>
```

I am able to display a tooltip but i want a  shadow around the tooltip.
What changes do i need to do in my current css?

Comment: Just notice, that adding `box-shadow` in `.tooltipDemo:hover:after` won't add shadow to the little triangle from `.tooltipDemo:hover:before`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add CSS3 `box-shadow` where you want the shadow to be appeared.
In your case

```
.tooltipDemo
        {           
            position: relative;
            display: inline;
            text-decoration: none;
            left: 5px;
            top: 0px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);     
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `.tooltipDemo:hover:after` to

```
.tooltipDemo:hover:after
{
    background: #fff;
    background: #E5E4E2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #666;
    width: 150px;
    left: 160px;
    top: -5px;
    content: attr(alt);
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    z-index: 95;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black; /*This line added*/
}
```

Check out this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/D6meL/)

Comment: This is adding the shadow to the box excluding the arrow mark.